# How to get cluster of lines using python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I have a lines dataset where each lines have several points (minimum 2). All the coordinates are known and on the same metric reference.

I would like to merge the lines with the same azimut +/- 10° and a maximal distance of 5cm between lines.

I think a clustering algorithm can do that, I found on web some clustering algorithms working with points and I would like to know if there is any existing function/algorithm to do that with lines ?
If no, I will try to adapt a code myself.

Comment: Consider having your x1, y1, x2, y2 as features and define a line segment distance metric as a custom distance function such as line segment Hausdorff distance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, almost all can be used. It's just probably not the most efficient way. Depending on how you'd formalize your problem, which is not clear enough. Do the points pairwise have to fulfill this property, or is it enough if they "mostly" do, or if there are some that do?

In many cases it will be easiest (but slow) to make a graph where you connect any two lines that have the desired property, then search for desirable structures such as cliques (and thenyou'll quickly see why it's not clear which solution you are looking for).

Comment: Thank's for the tips. Based on this answer and other cluster algorithm I find a way to do it efficiently (at least, more efficiently than iterations) on my data.
Actually, for thousands lines, the algorithm take ~6s :)

Comment: @Lionel Could you please elaborate in more detail how you solved your problem?